# Add Action Listeners AbstractTableModel for checkBox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable, actionlistener

I have a JTable using an AbstractTableModel.
Basically my program reads a folder and adds the files in the folder to the table.
I've set up my data Array like so:

```
public void buildPluginSheet(){
    String[] files= Files.getAvailableFiles();
    data.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        Object[] tmp = {files[i], version, new Boolean(isAvailable(files[i]))};
        data.add(tmp);
    }       
}
```

data is of the type ArrayList< Object[][] >

When you have a Boolean in the table it acts like a check box right? What I need is to be able to execute a function when the checkbox is checked and a different one when unchecked. Also, I have to be able to pass which row the checkbox was in so I can get the file name associated with the checkbox.

My AbstractTableModel looks like this:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4567658160237952337L;

    @Override 
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
        if(col == 2){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data.get(row)[col] = value;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data.get(row)[col];
    }
}
```

This is the code for the creation of my JTable:

```
    filesTable = new JTable(model);     
    filesTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    filesTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(550, 260));
    filesTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    filesTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    pluginsTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if(true){
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        }
    });
```

I've looked at many different solutions on here and other places, no luck.. 
I've tried different implementations of tableChanged and similar functions..
How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Take look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor

Comment: your model implementation is invalid: it must fire the appropriate event when changed. Also, *don't* make the model a listener (to what, anyway?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purposes you can use [`TableModelListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) in which you need to listen checkbox column and fire needed events. Here is simple example with `JCheckBox` in first column and listener for that:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {

        List<Object[]> l = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        l.add(new Object[]{true,1,2});
        l.add(new Object[]{true,3,4});

        MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel(new String[]{"1","2","3"},l);
        final JTable t = new JTable(model);
        t.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        t.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if(e.getColumn() == 0 && e.getFirstRow()>-1){
                    System.out.println("Row : " + e.getFirstRow() +
                            " value :" + t.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn()));
                }
            }
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Example();
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

        private String[] columnNames;
        private List<Object[]> data;

        public MyTableModel(String[] columnNames, List<Object[]> data ){
            this.columnNames = columnNames;
            this.data = data;

        }

        @Override 
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
            if(col == 0){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data.get(row)[col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
             if(column == 0){
                 return Boolean.class;
             }
            return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data.get(row)[col];
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

You need to call `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);` in your `TableModel` in `setValueAt()` method. I edited my code with minor changes in your model examine that. Also I recommend you to read [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for `JTable` model.

Comment: I tried that and I've updated my code above to match yours.. It still doesn't work...

Comment: Thank! I got it to work now. I was missing the fireTableCellUpdated() call inside setValueAt(). Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Table Changed listener to your table. Take a look at this link and go to the section "Listening for data changes":
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: I've tried that adding a simple print function so I'll know if it's being called. Also adding the listener to my table as well.. I'll update the code above.